# Overwrite part of text file in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a Java program that I need to output to a file.

This output file has a fixed structure, let's say a *header*, a *START* line, my output, an *END* line and a *footer*.

Everytime I run my program, I want it to write the output between those START-END parts. And if there's some text, I want to **overwrite** it.

By now, I'm reading line by line until I detect the *START* line, then I write my output. There's an "END" line after my output, as I said before.

My doubt is how can I overwrite the text between *START* and *END* (the older output) for every execution (the new output).

Comment: Where is your code? What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I can find the starting point to write, just after it finds the *START* line. The second time I run the program, if it's like this, it just appends the new output before the other one (right after the starting point to right...).

Comment: We can't find a bug in code, and suggest how to fix it, without seeing the code. Post your code.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't have a bug in the code, I'm just trying to discuss the best solution to adopt for my problem.

Comment: The best solution (the only one, in fact, unless your content always has the same length) is to rewrite the whole file: write the header, write the start line, write the new content, write the end line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class? I assume you have a variable length of body to be written between Header+START and END+Footer markers? This means you cannot just overwrite body part and expect tailing bytes to be pushed forward.

Maybe easiest implementation is how you started implement it anyway.

- Open RandomAccessFile access
- Find or skip to the end of START index, remember index
- Read bytes from the end backward until found a start of END index, bytes were put to a tailBuffer while reading backward (is backward ordered due to a reversed read-write)
- seek position back to STARTIndex+1 and write new body bytes to the end of start block
- call raf.setLength(startLen+bodylen+endLen) to trim or extend a new file length accordingly
- write tailBuffer to the end of file, make sure write is reversed in a proper order

This could be one way to implement this, or just read everything to RAM find indexes, overwite file with new content. This is fine if RAM is not an issue.